# JVM fairness while scheduling threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

Are there any assumptions on how fair JVM is when it comes to scheduling threads for execution?

For the below snippet, is it possible to have "code A" executed only, with B being ignored?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        for (;;) { /* code A */ }
      }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        for (;;) { /* code B */ }
      }
    }.start();

}
```

The question is more of a theoretical one - let's assume that neither of the threads gets blocked or otherwise encourages scheduler to switch context.

Comment: Your OS most likely support pre-emptive multi-tasking, in which case it will context switch these threads. If you have more than one free CPU, they will both run most of the time.

Comment: Good point re CPU number. Was thinking about only one CPU scenario.

Comment: Most computers have many CPUs these days, even mobile phones and Raspberry PIs. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any assumptions on how fair JVM is when it comes to scheduling threads for execution?

No.

> For the below snippet, is it possible to have "code A" executed only, with B being ignored?

In theory yes.

In practice:

- if there was one (available) core, I would expect the OS-level thread scheduler to time-slice the threads so that they each got roughly 50% of the available time in the log term
- if there were multiple (available) cores, I would expect the two threads to run in parallel.

---

Note that neither the JLS or the JVM spec says anything about thread scheduling or fairness.  Neither does the javadoc for `Thread`.

To my knowledge, the only Java API that mentions fairness is the `ReentrantLock` API ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)) where there is a constructor parameter for creating a lock with a fairness policy.  This means that the scheduler favors the thread that has been waiting the longest on the lock.  But even this is caveated:

> "Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling."

Comment: This assumes there is only one CPU. On a multi-CPU system with spare CPU there are likely to run almost all the time. +1